# freecell directx error

Tags: crash, directx

This is a weird error that has happened to me. Sometimes freecell closes with a directx error. Occurs at random times. Can anyone think of why this would occur? For the life of me, I don't know why freecell is using directx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Vista and Windows 7 versions of FreeCell use DirectX for simple 3D animations (previous versions did not have such animations).  This may be a problem with your video card or drivers.  Is the card overheating or damaged?  Are your drivers up to date and configured correctly?

**Edit:** There are reports of FreeCell causing conflicts with games such as *Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2*; see this [Microsoft Answers post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-gaming/failed-to-create-directx-device/b6979ca6-feb2-4dfe-8e5d-544b6cca4916).  Since games of this kind often require exclusive access to the video hardware, this may be the issue, especially if the error is "**Failed to create DirectX device**."  Unfortunately, you will probably need to close FreeCell before playing *Portal 2*; this shouldn't be an issue as current versions of FreeCell can save the game on closing.

Comment: This is the only time I see the error, so I would assume not.

Comment: Do any other 3D applications malfunction in any way?

Comment: Not that I can tell. It usually happened while I was playing portal 2. Portal kept on running, but freecell died.

Comment: Can FreeCell run by itself without problems?  What is your video card model?  This sounds like there is a conflict between those two applications.

Comment: Yes, Nvidia GTS 360M

Comment: It looks like Portal 2 is trying to make exclusive use of the GPU, and in doing so causes FreeCell to not have the required resources to render its graphics properly.  Turning off animations in FreeCell while Portal 2 is running may solve the problem.

Comment: Got it. But why does it not crash every time then?

Comment: Honestly, I have never heard of one 3D program crashing another.  Once again, are your video drivers up to date?

Comment: I just got my drivers up to date. Should it crash again, I will reopen this. Thank you.